# Better Linq parsing of Large XML data

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an app that takes in a number of xml files and carries out lookups in order to create a csv file, i notice the data isnt always 100% ie a missing result or 2 so i figure the way i am handling the data is incorrect and poor so would really appreciate some assistance from the gurus on here.

Small XML Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lookupdb xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:sample:lookupdb:0.1">
    <References>
          <Reference id="3cb7ceb0-43c7-4c67-a7fb-fffb32fc71c4">
            <Vehicle>Beach_Buggy_01</Vehicle>
            <Engineers>
              <Engineer>Joe Bloggs</Engineer>
            </Engineers>
            <IsActive>true</IsActive>
            <Owner>Bill Bloggs</Owner>
            <Serviced>True</Serviced>
            <OwnerName>Bill</OwnerName>
            <CostID>ABCDEF123456</CostID>
            <FuelType>Petrol</FuelType>
            <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
            <Address>Some Address</Address>
          </Reference>
          <Reference id="d1053bd3-a1cb-4fb4-a7d5-ffee3e10ffdb">
            <Vehicle>Transit</Vehicle>
            <Engineers>
              <Engineer>Joe Bloggs2</Engineer>
            </Engineers>
            <IsActive>true</IsActive>
            <Owner>Andy Bloggs</Owner>
            <Serviced>True</Serviced>
            <OwnerName>Andy</OwnerName>
            <CostID>9345089</CostID>
            <FuelType>Petrol</FuelType>
            <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
            <Address>Some Address4</Address>
          </Reference>
          <Reference id="30f8cfe8-40fd-4c99-9c7d-5ab98f8e5620">
            <Vehicle>Ford Fiesta</Vehicle>
            <Engineers>
              <Engineer>Steve Bloggs</Engineer>
            </Engineers>
            <IsActive>true</IsActive>
            <Owner>Sarah H</Owner>
            <Serviced>True</Serviced>
            <OwnerName>Bill</OwnerName>
            <CostID>834hsdfgs</CostID>
            <FuelType>Petrol</FuelType>
            <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
            <Address>Some Address3</Address>
          </Reference>
    </References>
    <Sessions>
        <RentalSession id="cc5d9960-3a80-4fd9-b7d6-0963198567c3">
              <VehicleRefId>3cb7ceb0-43c7-4c67-a7fb-fffb32fc71c4</VehicleRefId>
              <RentalPeriod startDate="2018-10-02T07:46:34Z" endDate="2018-10-02T08:27:36Z" />
              <HiringInfo HireId="2e428f42-f8f1-4603-9570-fed1fa78e470" customerId="1929936734" customerRefId="6da73407-f443-491d-9cad-c4fed9bfb71f" />
              <Notes>Vehicle Broke Down Recovery ordered</Notes>
              <VehicleGroup>ATV</VehicleGroup>
        </RentalSession>
        <RentalSession id="829221a2-196e-403a-bdcb-9759959cfa70">
              <VehicleRefId>3cb7ceb0-43c7-4c67-a7fb-fffb32fc71c4</VehicleRefId>
              <RentalPeriod startDate="2018-10-03T07:46:34Z" endDate="2018-10-04T08:27:36Z" />
              <HiringInfo HireId="4fb2cd21-9f48-44de-ae72-01ce4eeccdf9" customerId="2929936735" customerRefId="0a2d3d8b-ab06-4cd1-9ec5-aea4ac3f6da3" />
              <Notes>Returned on Time no Damage</Notes>
              <VehicleGroup>ATV</VehicleGroup>
        </RentalSession>
        <RentalSession id="68a6b485-d30a-439a-8081-8c09f724d23b">
              <VehicleRefId>d1053bd3-a1cb-4fb4-a7d5-ffee3e10ffdb</VehicleRefId>
              <RentalPeriod startDate="2018-10-05T07:46:34Z" endDate="2018-10-05T08:27:36Z" />
              <HiringInfo HireId="c4022764-7fc2-4415-97bf-57d616e3b8bd" customerId="3929936736" customerRefId="cb260bfc-34c1-4ac5-befa-17f69b2406bb" />
              <Notes>Scratch to Door Charges applied</Notes>
              <VehicleGroup>VANS</VehicleGroup>
        </RentalSession>
        <RentalSession id="c4083f9a-65ee-4693-8488-e299271064b1">
              <VehicleRefId>30f8cfe8-40fd-4c99-9c7d-5ab98f8e5620</VehicleRefId>
              <RentalPeriod startDate="2018-10-09T07:46:34Z" endDate="2018-10-09T08:27:36Z" />
              <HiringInfo HireId="cb260bfc-34c1-4ac5-befa-17f69b2406bb" customerId="4929936737" customerRefId="c4022764-7fc2-4415-97bf-57d616e3b8bd" />
              <Notes>Generally a rubbish vehicle</Notes>
              <VehicleGroup>Small Cars</VehicleGroup>
        </RentalSession>
    </Sessions>
</lookupdb>
```

The Username is the main lookup of the program along with the engineer being required as seen the VehicleRefId in sessions matches the Reference id, with the bulk of the data being taken from the rental sessions; however from some local tests i found that grabbing the session data first seemed to work better but not entirely sure on this approach, here is the code that i think needs looking at:

1: Grabbing the Rental Data

```
 var result = xDoc.Descendants().Descendants(ns + "RentalSession")
                            .Where(x => x.Element(ns + "VehicleRefId").Value != null)
                            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                _VehicleRefId = GetResultValue(true, x, "VehicleRefId", "VehicleRefId", "Vehicle Reference ID"),
                                _RentalSessionId = GetResultValue(false, x, "RentalSession", "id", "Session ID"),
                                _startDate = GetResultValue(false, x, "RentalPeriod", "startDate", "Start date"),
                                _endDate = GetResultValue(false, x, "RentalPeriod", "endDate", "End date"),
                                _VehicleGroup = GetResultValue(true, x, "VehicleGroup", "VehicleGroup", "Vehicle Group"),
                                _Notes = GetResultValue(true, x, "Notes", "Notes", "Event Notes")
                            }).ToList().Distinct();
```

2: Method seen in the rental data lookup query:

```
private string GetResultValue(bool isNode, XElement atrr_value,string nodeName, string xattr_Name, string value_text)
{
    string retValue = "";
    try
    {
        switch(isNode)
        {
            case true:
                    retValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)atrr_value.Element(ns + nodeName).Value)
                                       ? (string)atrr_value.Element(ns + nodeName).Value
                                          : $"No {value_text} Found.";
                    break;
            default:
                    if(nodeName == "RentalSession")
                    {
                        retValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)atrr_value.Attribute(xattr_Name).Value)
                                       ? (string)atrr_value.Attribute(xattr_Name).Value
                                          : $"No {value_text} Found.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        retValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)atrr_value.Element(ns + nodeName).Attribute(xattr_Name).Value)
                                       ? (string)atrr_value.Element(ns + nodeName).Attribute(xattr_Name).Value
                                          : $"No {value_text} Found.";
                    }
                    break;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception rex)
    {
        retValue = "null";
    }

    return retValue;
}
```

3: Grabbing the Owner and Engineer data:

```
foreach(var itemData in result)
{
    try
    {
        var references = xDoc.Descendants().Descendants(ns + "Reference")
                         .Where(
                                a => a.Attribute("id").Value == itemData._VehicleRefId
                               )
                         .Select(a => new
                         {
                                _OwnerName = a.Element(ns + "OwnerName").Value,
                                _Engineer = a.Elements(ns + "Engineers").Descendants(ns + "Engineer").Select(e => e.Value).Single()
                         }).FirstOrDefault();

                         ... Further parsing 
    catch (Exception xEx)
    {
        //some error handling stuff
    }
}
```

Really appreciate the assist in order to understand where i fall short in a bid to learn and streamline this section of code.

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: The above xml only shows one section of data there will be multiple references and sessions and some sessions will match the same reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your XmlSerializer compatible classes from [**xmltocsharp**](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/).

Copy and paste your Xml inside editor of above link and click `Convert` button to get your classes.

By this way you will easily get your any desired xml node or attribute value by [Dot] notation of classes object.

Here i created a console app for your demonstration purpose.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Nullplex6\source\repos\ConsoleApp4\ConsoleApp4\Files\XMLFile9.xml");
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Lookupdb));
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            Lookupdb lookupdb = (Lookupdb)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            //Here you can get any xml node and attribute value of single "RentalSession" in "Sessions" by passig id to where clause
            RentalSession rentalSession = lookupdb.Sessions.RentalSession.Where(x => x.Id == "68a6b485-d30a-439a-8081-8c09f724d23b").FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine("Id: " + rentalSession.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("VehicleRefId: " + rentalSession.VehicleRefId);
            Console.WriteLine("EndDate: " + rentalSession.RentalPeriod.EndDate);
            Console.WriteLine("VehicleGroup: " + rentalSession.VehicleGroup);

            Console.WriteLine();

            //Here you can get any xml node and attribute value of single "Reference"  in "References" by passig id to where clause
            Reference reference = lookupdb.References.Reference.Where(x => x.Id == "d1053bd3-a1cb-4fb4-a7d5-ffee3e10ffdb").FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine("OwnerName: " + reference.OwnerName);
            Console.WriteLine("Engineer: " + reference.Engineers.Engineer);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for this i will need to test and see how i can carry out lookups / loop in order to map the correct data as its likely to have multiple sections ie multiple rentals for different reference ids that need to map. so far i like the url you posted as it definitely saves some time

Comment: Yes its easily map your multiple sections or rentals. If you have multiple RentalSession  in single xml file then xmlserializer classes slightly change. Could u plz add such file so I'll update my answer :)

Comment: Or if u have multiple RentalSession  u can do it yourself also just change the property from "public RentalSession RentalSession { get; set; }" to "public List<RentalSession> RentalSession { get; set; }" in class  Sessions and by using linq or lambda expression you can get specific RentalSession by providing RentalSessionId  in where clause

Comment: Thanks again have updated the xml and working in the background on this,  literally learning at the moment about xml processes hence my issues and speed :( i do appreciate what you are doing so far

Comment: I'd update my answer according to and  you can get your single `RentalSession` and `Reference` from collection of `RentalSessions` and `References` by supplying id in where clause.

Comment: If u found my answer is helpful then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green and vote up by clicking up arrow to my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the assist, i will mark this as an answer as i have enjoyed toying with this solution and have learned something new in the process.
I did manage to get my own working correctly as it seems i had an ordering issue which was skewing the results, however as said i really like this so thanks truly appreciated.

Comment: @Psymon25, glad to hear that you have get rid from your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "Value" property which gives issues when a element is null.  Instead do a cast like code below

```
var result = xDoc.Descendants().Descendants(ns + "RentalSession")
                            .Where(x => x.Element(ns + "VehicleRefId").Value != null)
                            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                _VehicleRefId = (string)x.Element("VehicleRefId"),
                                _RentalSessionId = (string)x.Element("RentalSession),
                                _startDate = (DateTime)x.Element("RentalPeriod),
                                _endDate = (DateTime)x.Element("RentalPeriod"),
                                _VehicleGroup = (string)x.Element("VehicleGroup"),
                                _Notes = (string)x.Element("Notes")
                            }).ToList().Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response i do cast in the above method: GetResultValue but maybe i need to do as you say and exclude the value reference, will test and post back here.